# Hadoop Mapreduce wordcount

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar, word-count

What is the difference in running Hadoop MapReduce WordCount program from Eclipse Kepler and running it with pre-defined jar file located in Mapreduce (hadoop-mapreduce-example-2.6.0.jar).
Is there any difference with speed,performance etc..

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Just that when your input is huge and you have mapper/reducer running on multiple nodes, you would see drastic performance improvement as now the word counting will be done in parallel across different machines.

Comment: u mean running mapper and reducer in different system !!

Comment: Yes you would have multiple instances of mapper/reducer running on different machines and all would process your request in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your map-reduce from eclipse (i.e. without building .jar and directly running by clicking run program) then you are actually running the map-reduce in **pseudo** mode(mostly used for testing purpose).

To run a program in pseudo mode, you don't really need to have hadoop installed. You just need hadoop jar files.

But when you use hadoop-mapreduce-example-2.6.0.jar (I.e. you write command to run it on terminal) you are actually running the mapreduce on live cluster (Hadoop). For this you need your Hadoop cluster up and running.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `WordCount` program in Eclipse, you are mimicking the actual behaviour locally which will be run on real hadoop engine. It acts like you have a local cluster but it's not. When you run it through the JAR, the JAR contains the `.class` file which gives the real cluster a hint how the Map and Reduce should work. 
If the input file size is huge it's broken into multiple splits and processed accordingly and the output is stored into `HDFS` and not just logged in the console.